# create a div with beveled edge (Html,Css)

Tags: html, css, border

I would like to create a div or a section that has the edge in the bottom of your content inside normal and oblique. the result should be like this:
http://themeforest.net/item/delicious-responsive-app-landing-html-theme/full_screen_preview/7965552 
can someone help me?

Comment: We will need the code you have to answer efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you have given uses images with a transparent background.

It is possible in CSS.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7PL4/)

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  height:200px;
  width:1000px;
  background:indianred;
  margin-top:250px;
  position:relative;
}

div::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid indianred;
  border-left: 1000px solid transparent;
  top:-100px;
}

div::after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid indianred;
  border-right: 1000px solid transparent;
  bottom:-100px;
}
```

If you want browser compatibility, you'll have to stick with the image method.

Comment: Im on the latest chrome on osx and there is no bevel in your image.

Comment: Hence my last comment, `if you want browser compatibility, you'll have to stick with the image method`. It doesn't work for all browsers. Sorry man. @DanStayntouch

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background trick:

```
<div class="div1">
    content 1
</div>
<div> content 2</div>


.div1 {
    background: linear-gradient(352deg, transparent 125px, #c00 0) bottom right;}
```

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2f7Ds/

Comment: adapted from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349867/how-do-i-bevel-the-corners-of-an-element