# Is there an SVG Method to doing beveled corners on DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, frontend

I have been trying to find a way to give div elements a consistent beveled edge. Think paper like in Battlestar Galactica - see image below, I circled what I mean by bevel. To set things up more, these block div elements can be different sizes and dynamically expand / contract with content. Even when they do, I want the bevel to stay a consistent size (as long as there is enough room to bevel)

Basically I need a squared off version of the rounded corner CSS border radius property

[image: Beveled Corners]

I have tried methods including Jquery Corner Plugin (seems to no longer work, be maintained, and from documentation only works with a solid background color which wont work for me), Old school DIV generation (lacks transparency underneath so ruins effect), and multiple other methods.

Apparently there is a CSS feature draft pending on adding border-corner-shape, which would do exactly what I want, https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-border-shape/ but its not approved. From an article on Medium, this feature may not be due to lack of developers demanding this feature. (+1 my vote for adding this, who do I beg?)

So, I got to thinking, and it seems this may be possible using SVG. However, although I could see SVG being a solution to build the right shape, I have absolutely no clue how to do this, and a few bad attempts ended in SVG mess all over. Frankly, I don't even know if this can be used given the divs will be different shapes. Disclaimer, I am not a front end web developer, but working on a personal project requiring me to dabble. So I figured I would ask the experts.

Has someone created an SVG solution for this and I am just not seeing it in the 20 odd pages of search results I dug through? Does this seem possible? If likely possible and not done yet, how would one going about this? Is there a better solution to bevel a corner? Is there a simpler option I am overlooking?

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349867/how-do-i-bevel-the-corners-of-an-element and https://codepen.io/aternus/pen/mqqXdK

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was tried. Sorry, there has been so many methods tried, it became hard to remember to mention them all. It broke down when you attempted to give the background of the element any sort of color. The background color would show both inside and outside the corner - no ability to mask,

Comment: I think I am close.... but I don't think my transforms are right. There are little artifacts in the corners where it looks like my box is still not rotating at center point ( for some reason putting in the X and Y of half the box height and width did not work as I thought it would so I had to guess coordinates...)

Can someone help get this to the finishline? https://jsfiddle.net/15u24ocq/4/

Comment: Please check my answer, let me know if it solves your problem or if there is anything else you need.

Comment: OK, I have something working, https://jsfiddle.net/89n7kgma/12/

But still don't understand why I can't move the pivot like I want. Going 0, -35 on translation makes no sense to me and was derived by guess and check. I would have thought it would have been 25,25 to offset the translation point to the center of the 50x50 object then just rotate 45 degrees. What is going on here? I want to understand SVG translations better.

Comment: Note, apparently only one of the four corners in my solution clips in chrome and edge. From exploration, it looks as if chrome and edge don't respect the % positioning values of the three clone elements. But work if you manually do pixel values (not practical). If anyone has a solution I am all ears.

Comment: The "35" is because the corner of the square is 25 * sqrt(2) = 35.3553 away from the centre.

Comment: BTW your fiddle works fine for me in Chrome. All corners are masked properly.  (Win10; Chrome 87.0.4280.88; Edge 87.0.664.60).

Comment: Paul, you are my hero. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS Clip Path property to basically clip any div (or any element for that matter) into any shape that you need. Please see the example that I'm showing below:

**Note:** Clip Path doesn't care about the borders itself, it just cuts your entire element to the shape specified. So you need to make sure you add enough padding so the content doesn't get chopped.

Also, you may use the CSS shape-outside property if you want the clipped div to also have a bevelled shape in the DOM (not just visually but the actual shape).

Here's the official MDN documentation for Clip Path : [CSS Clip Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
.bevelled{
background-color:red;
clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
}

.bevelled-borders{
background-color:cyan;
clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bevelled"></div>
<br/>
<div class="bevelled-borders"></div>
```

Comment: A good thought, and this works fine for squares, but breaks as soon as the div is turned into a rectangle as that forces the corners to become odd angles. As those angles change every div based on how wide or tall the div is, visually it is undesired. Crisp corners that maintain identical angle on all sides for all divs, regardless of  dimensions are needed. 

The solution I posted above seems to be working fine, though I would still like to better understand pivot translations as the correct translation point was a bit guess and check, and not the initially predicted outcome.